# Bash script doesn't continue when condition fulfilled

Tags: bash

To check the validity of lines in a file I'm using a condition which is met when `egrep -v` does NOT return an empty result. When there are invalid lines, then this works fine (i.e. the conditional block is executed), but when every line is valid then the script ends without further processing.

Script:

```
INVALID_HOSTS=$(egrep -v ${IP_REGEX} hosts)
if [[ ! -z "${INVALID_HOSTS}" ]]; then
    echo "Invalid hosts:"
    for entry in ${INVALID_HOSTS}
        do echo ${entry}
    done
    exit_with_error_msg "hosts file contains invalid hosts (Pattern must be: \"\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+:\d+\"), exiting"
else
    echo "all cool"
fi
echo "after if-else"
```

So when there are no invalid lines then neither the `echo "all cool"` nor `echo "after if-else"` get executed. The script just stops and returns to the shell.

When `set -x` is enabled, then it prints:

```
++ egrep -v '^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?):([1-9]|[1-5]?[0-9]{2,4}|6[1-4][0-9]{3}|65[1-4][0-9]{2}|655[1-2][0-9]|6553[1-5])$' hosts
+ INVALID_HOSTS=
```

Playing around with it I'm sure that it's about the `if [[ ! -z "${INVALID_HOSTS}" ]]; then`, but my bash wizardry is not strong enough to overcome this magical barrier.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When there are no invalid hosts, do you see a "Invalid hosts:" displayed?

Comment: @lurker no, it just returns to the shell. Without any error. Just as a script would after the last line.

Comment: Two problems to fix before you try to debug this further: quote `$IP_REGEX`, and see [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the proper way to iterate over the output of a command.

Comment: `[[ ! -z "${INVALID_HOSTS}" ]]` double negation = same as `[[ -n "${INVALID_HOSTS}" ]]`. See: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2236

Comment: Are you sure that in `INVALID_HOSTS=$(egrep -v ${IP_REGEX} hosts)` you did not mean `INVALID_HOSTS=$(egrep -v ${IP_REGEX} /etc/hosts)` instead? If you are running with `errorexit` or `-e` flag, `egrep` not finding your `hosts` file would trigger an `errorexit` rule, and so terminate your script prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment. I'll start it as an answer and we can work our way through further details or I can scrap it entirely if not helpful. I'll make some assumptions and let us see if it hits the spot.

For starters, you do indeed use the value further, so command expansion into a variable is not entirely useless, but otherwise it's much easier to determine match (or lack thereof) of `grep` through it's return value. If anything matched (output would be non-empty), it returns (shell `true`) value of `0`, otherwise it returns `false` (in this case `1`). Not to mention the `! -z` test notation should really be `-n` if used at all.

And this is where I'd start assuming a bit. I suspect this is not your entire script and you have `errexit` option turned on in that shell session (or through `rc` file in general). Either by means of `set -o errexit` or `set -e` or running bash with `-e` option. Since `grep` not matching anything returns as failed, your shell (script execution) would terminate after having encountered a failing command.

Observe the difference between:

```
$ bash -ec 'grep "BOGUS" /etc/fstab  ; echo "$?"'
$ bash -c 'grep "BOGUS" /etc/fstab  ; echo "$?"'
1
```

With `errexit`, bash terminates after grep has "failed" and we never even reach the `echo`.

---

Since the assumption has proven to be correct, small extension. If `errexit` is what you want, you'd need to either change the option value before/after a command you want to be able to fail (return non-zero value) without affecting your script:

```
set +o errexit
grep THIS_COULD_NOT_MATCH...
set -o errexit
```

Or you can ignore return value of individual commands by ensuring their success:

```
grep THIS_COULD_NOT_MATCH... || true
```

You can also still use potentially "failing" commands safely in conditionals (such as `if`) without terminating your shell.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. `set -e` was on. Without it the script continues. Thanks!

Comment: yw. I keep making that point in all reviews done for my colleagues... modifying default behavior is all well, if conscious, reflected and taken into account in the rest of your script. If you wanted to retain the behavior and continue past commands that could fail without relevance to us, you'd need to slap `|| true` to that line... or manipulate `errexit` before/after as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very enlightening answer. @ToWhomItMayConcern To catch such "unintuitive" errors you can add `trap 'echo "Exit code: $?"' EXIT` after the `set -e`. This will "catch the exception" and print the exit code before exiting. So when such error occurs you can then explicitly add `|| true` to the respective command to let it return exit code 0, as Ondrej mentioned, if the command acted as expected.